# Strange Robots.txt update problems

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a strange robots.txt issue.
I update my robots file regularly without problem, until some days ago. Now, when I update the robots via a FTP folder it appears to update. If I view it from a browsers, I only see the old version. Even Google doesn't update it, after several days. From Google's search console I see this: [image]

On the left you see what I see in my browser and what google sees. On the right you see the real file, like it appears in ftp. The last 5 lines are different.

If it matters, I use Google's DNS servers. When I change the DNS on my PC connection to my Internet Service Provider's DNS, I see the new robots file, but google still does not.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, as my robots.txt wouldn't show correctly to Google in days. It can take a while for Google to crawl your site and check your robots.txt - sometimes its done right away, sometimes it can take up to a few days. I would suggest you to wait for a while and check again. Maybe even try from a computer with a different network (or a mobile network).

I recommend that you try and upload (if you haven't already) your file to Google for faster crawling. Check out this link - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6078399?hl=en

Comment: No you don't undestand. I've asked google to update my robots, since 5 days, every 10 hours.. The problem is that google don't see the updated version. Also me, with google DNS, can't see the updated version. Instead if I change my DNS connection parameters, I can see the updated version. But google still can't

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the cloudflare cache.. Flushed it the problem was solved